# Balancing performance heavy procedures with real-time mouse input

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

To put this question succinctly, is there any way to offer a real-time web application that requires processing to be done at every coordinate that a user moves their mouse to without dropping any mouse events?

With JS, if we want to keep track of the user's mouse location, we're essentially limited to attaching a `mousemove` handler to some element. Unfortunately, if we're using the mouse location to perform some expensive procedures such as drawing dynamic graphics to the screen via WebGL or a 2D canvas, we can (and typically do) lose a lot of accuracy.

For instance, if we link the user's mouse to a camera in a first-person WebGL game and the user is moving around erratically, some of the immersion will be lost as the camera fails to accurately mimic where the mouse is pointed. Or, even more simply, if we want to stamp multiple images onto a 2D canvas wherever the user drags the cursor, chances are we won't be able to produce a nice smooth curve if the user happens to draw one.

Ultimately, since JS is single-threaded we can't just have a separate thread running with the sole purpose of collecting mouse coordinates and let the application process the input as fast as it can (maybe a web worker would help here?). Similarly, we can't very easily prioritize collecting mouse events over the processing that needs to happen, because we can quickly start starving the processing side of things.

Is there some sort of approach that I'm overlooking here? If all an app does is record mouse coordinates, you typically get a very accurate record of where the mouse has been. The problem arises when we have to do some significant, but not unreasonable, processing based on that input in real-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing, you may be able to interleave your processing with event handling by working a little at a time in a timeout handler. This gives the event handlers a chance to fire in between.

```
var workInterval = 0; // or try other small values
function doABitOfWork() {
    // ... Do stuff, but don't take too long ...
    if (!finished) {
        setTimeout(doABitOfWork, workInterval);
    }
}
setTimeout(doABitOfWork, workInterval);
```

I've used this trick successfully to make the page responsive while constructing a heavy HTML table.

Comment: I used the same techniques but different methods for a "real-time" application with some heavy constructing. This technique also makes it possible for the user to keep interacting with the browser during the processing. Which is a must to make it appear "real". In the end it's(user-experience) all about the illusion, it doesn't matter how you pull it.

Comment: That's actually a pretty elegant and straight-forward solution to this issue. Web workers seem like a slight possibility here, too. I'll have to cook up some tests and see what's possible. @dizas You're definitely right--this is very much a user experience issue. Thanks guys!

Comment: A word of warning: structuring your background work so that you can return from it often enough may require extensive refactoring. JavaScript doesn't have continuations unfortunately.

Comment: @mpartel You're definitely correct. Thankfully, a major plus here is that apps requiring this level of interaction are, for the most part, stateful. With a bit of extra planning to make sure the jobs are manageable in short periods of time, picking up where you left off shouldn't be too horrible. Things will end up being slightly more convoluted, but the benefit would be extremely worth it.